# "Qual'è" o "Qual è"?

Tags: grammar, orthography, apocope

Buongiorno,

Fino ad oggi pensavo che bisognasse mettere l'apostrofo dopo qual, essendo una forma tagliata di quale, ma su Quora ho trovato molte domande che usavano qual senza l'apostrofo, dunque mi è venuto il dubbio.

Qual è la forma corretta? Sono entrambi giusti o usati, e se sì, allora qual è la differenza?

Comment: Mi sono permesso di correggere, perché la forma corretta è appunto “qual è”, anche se non ho tempo di formulare una risposta, che arriverà di sicuro molto presto.

Comment: Sono scioccato che questa domanda non fosse già su questo sito: si tratta forse del più comune errore della lingua italiana...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Come riportato nella [risposta al quesito sull’Accademia della  Crusca](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/lesatta-grafia-qual), la forma corretta è *qual è*:

> **Esatta grafia di *qual è*** 
> **L'esatta grafia di *qual è* non prevede
> l'apostrofo** in quanto si tratta di un'apocope vocalica, che si produce
> anche davanti a consonante (qual buon vento vi porta?) e non di
> un'elisione che invece si produce soltanto prima di una vocale (e
> l'apostrofo è il segno grafico che resta proprio nel caso
> dell'elisione). Come qual ci sono altri aggettivi soggetti allo stesso
> trattamento: *tal*, *buon*, *pover* (solo nell'italiano antico), ecc. È vero
> che la grafia *qual'è* è diffusa e ricorrente anche nella stampa, ma per
> ora questo non è bastato a far cambiare la regola grafica che pertanto
> è consigliabile continuare a rispettare.

[Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/qual-e-o-qual-e_%28La-grammatica-italiana%29/) riporta similmente la seguente spiegazione:

> **QUAL È O QUAL’È**?
>  **La grafia corretta nell’italiano contemporaneo è *qual è*, senza apostrofo.** La grafia *qual’è*, anche se
> molto diffusa, è scorretta, perché non si tratta di un caso di
> ➔elisione, ma di ➔troncamento, dal momento che *qual* esiste come forma
> autonoma. La grafia *qual’è* con l’apostrofo è presente nella
> letteratura del passato, anche recente
>
> Qual’è il piacere che volete da me? (C. Collodi, *Le avventure di
> Pinocchio*)
>
> Do un’occhiata alla casa e capisco qual’è la camera (F.
> Tozzi, *Ricordi di un impiegato*). 
> ***DUBBI*** 
>  
> Naturalmente anche *qual era* si
> scrive senza apostrofo. Invece *qual’erano* si scrive con l’apostrofo,
> perché viene da *quali erano*, con elisione di *quali*.

Treccani ribadisce che l’uso dell’apostrofo, sebbene molto diffuso, è scorretto.